# MavenFilteringException missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, java-6

I am getting below exception while compiling my project(on java6) with maven 3.2.5 and local repository and have all required jars downloaded.
The project builds fine with maven2.0 and we are upgrading to 3.2.5. Have all required dependency jars downloaded, but it still complains with below error even when I see maven-filtering jar present in repository.

Also, I tried below options but still the error is same. Is there any other place or setting I am missing here?

- copied maven-filtering 1.1 in repository-new\org\apache\maven\shared
- copied maven-filtering 3.1.1 in repository-new\org\apache\maven\shared
- cleaned up .m2 local cache
- copied maven-filtering 1.1 in repository-new\org\apache\maven\maven-filtering
- copied maven-filtering 3.1.1 in   repository-new\org\apache\maven\maven-filtering

Error stack trace:

```
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/coding/repository-new/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/repository-new/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources: org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/coding/repository-new/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/codingrepository-new/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:166)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources: org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/coding//repository-new/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/coding//repository-new/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:164)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1838)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:657)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:875)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:798)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:281)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:213)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:998)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:994)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1044)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:122)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:464)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:119)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 54 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :my-proj
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the **maven-resource-plugin** version being used in the project is not matching with the resources used by the maven version you are using.
Try maven-resource-plugin version **2.4** in the project
if the plugin is not already there in the project pom. Add it as below inside the **build -> plugins** section.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```